# calculating mean in differences in grouped variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset with 5 levels of a treatment for a response variable.

Assume, I measured soil N content at 5 levels (optimal, 40%, 30%, 20%, and 10%) of soil water content. And for each level I have 5 replicates.

Now, I would like to calculate unstandardized (optimal - 40%, optimal - 30%, optimal - 20%, optimal - 10%) and standardized (optimal - 40% / optimal, optimal - 30% / optimal, and so on) for each replicate.

Is there any way to do this in R with Tidyverse? I am having problems with making 'loop' functions. Five replicates for each treatment level.

```
df<- data.frame(Soilwater = c("optimal", "optimal", "optimal", "optimal", "optimal", 
       "40", "40", "40", "40", "40", 
       "30","30","30","30","30", 
       "20", "20","20","20","20",
       "10","10","10","10","10", 
       "optimal", "optimal", "optimal", "optimal", "optimal", 
       "40", "40", "40", "40", "40", 
       "30","30","30","30","30", 
       "20", "20","20","20","20",
       "10","10","10","10","10"), 
Diversity = c("High","High","High","High","High","High","High","High","High","High",   "High","High","High","High","High","High","High","High","High","High",
       "High","High","High","High","High", 
       "Low", "Low", "Low","Low","Low","Low","Low","Low","Low","Low",
       "Low","Low","Low","Low","Low","Low","Low","Low","Low","Low",
       "Low","Low","Low","Low","Low"),
Soil_N = c(50,45, 49, 48, 49, 69, 68, 69, 70, 67, 79, 78, 79, 78, 77, 89, 89, 87, 88, 89, 99, 98, 97, 98, 98, 120,    
   121,    121,    120,    122,    134,    131,    132,    134,    131,    145,    148,    149,    147,    
   148,    159,    159,    157,    156,    157,    169,    167,    167,    168,    164))
```

I used the code below that was suggested by @JonSpring which was really helpful.

```
df %>%
    # First, we can add a `Replicate` number based on position within 
    # each Soilwater/Diversity cohort.
    group_by(Soilwater, Diversity) %>%
    mutate(Replicate = row_number()) %>%

    # Calc diff vs. experiment with same Diversity & Replicate, optimal Soilwater 
    group_by(Diversity, Replicate) %>%
    mutate(Difference = Soil_N - Soil_N[Soilwater == "optimal"]) %>%

    # Summarize avg diffs
    group_by(Soilwater, Diversity) %>%
    summarize(Mean_Diff = mean(Difference), .groups = "drop")
```

However, I realized that first I need to make an average for the `optimal` Soilwater level and then calculate the difference between this average and each replicate from other Soilwater levels for which I tried the code below (with the `mean` function to calculate the average of `optimal` soilwater before the difference). But it is not working.

```
df%>%       group_by(Soilwater, Diversity)%>%       mutate(Replicate = row_number())%>%        
group_by(Diversity, Replicate)%>%       mutate(Difference = mean(Soil_N[Soilwater=="optimal"])- Soil_N)
```

Comment: "Now, I would like to calculate unstandardized (optimal - 40%, optimal -30%, optimal - 20%, optimal - 10%) and standardized (optimal - 40% / optimal, optimal - 30% / optimal, and so on) for each replicate." 
Calculate what?

Comment: Also some of your code isn't formatted as code and it's difficult to understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult to understand your problem. So I start from what seems to work with you.

As a newcomer to R and tidyverse, please be cognisant that the `%>%` (pipe) chains your operations on the (starting) object.
You can assign any state/stage of your operations to a new object (aka variable).

I further recommend that you create several "interim" objects as you work your problems to store steps of your problem/algorithm. This will give you a better feel of what you have. Over time you will then get enough experience to chain the operations and avoid some of the - interim - stages/object.

For that purpose, I introduce an "interim" result/object as your description suggested this worked - up to that point for you, i.e. I assign `interim_df <- ...`

```
library(dplyr)

interim_df <- df %>%
    group_by(Soilwater, Diversity)  %>%
    mutate(Replicate = row_number()) %>%
    group_by(Diversity, Replicate)
```

This yields an object `interim_df`. Let's have a look at it

```
interim_df
# A tibble: 50 x 4
# Groups:   Diversity, Replicate [10]
   Soilwater Diversity Soil_N Replicate
   <chr>     <chr>      <dbl>     <int>
 1 optimal   High          50         1
 2 optimal   High          45         2
 3 optimal   High          49         3
 4 optimal   High          48         4
 5 optimal   High          49         5
 6 40        High          69         1
 7 40        High          68         2
 8 40        High          69         3
 9 40        High          70         4
10 40        High          67         5
```

Ok. We got a tibble 50 rows with 4 variables ... that seem to be the datastructure your are happy with.
What you also have is a "grouped dataframe". Be sure to `ungroup()` when you want to operate on the whole (or other part of the dataframe).

```
interim_df <- interim_df %>% ungroup()
```

You can "extract" your "optimal" measurements and calculate the average over this "new" df/tibble.

```
mean_optimal <- interim_df %>%
    filter(Soilwater == "optimal") %>%
    summarise(MeanOptimal = mean(SoilN)   # we calculate/summarise the mean over the part we want
```

This gives you

```
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  MeanOptimal
        <dbl>
1        84.5
```

To be clear, we have now another tibble with 1 variable/column.
This can be used in your `interim_df`. However, make sure to understand how to "extract" a column from a tibble (aka make it a vector to reuse).
The base-R notation `$` gives you direct access to a column (vector); tidyverse offers the `pull()` function.

```
final <- interim_df %>% mutate(Difference = mean_optimal$MeanOptimal - Soil_N)
final
# A tibble: 50 x 5
   Soilwater Diversity Soil_N Replicate Difference
   <chr>     <chr>      <dbl>     <int>      <dbl>
 1 optimal   High          50         1       34.5
 2 optimal   High          45         2       39.5
 3 optimal   High          49         3       35.5
 4 optimal   High          48         4       36.5
 5 optimal   High          49         5       35.5
 6 40        High          69         1       15.5
 7 40        High          68         2       16.5
 8 40        High          69         3       15.5
 9 40        High          70         4       14.5
10 40        High          67         5       17.5
```

You can also "add" your mean_optimal$MeanOptimal to the interim_df as a new column by `interim_df %>% mutate(MeanOptimal = mean_optimal$MeanOptimal)` and then do the difference.

Comment: I will be better next times. Everything seem to work from your answer except that I have to make the differences between 'optimal' and other water levels separately for low and high diversity level. I calculated mean_optimal for each diversity level as below that gave me a tibble to 2x2.     '''   mean_optimal<- interim_df%>%
  group_by(Diversity)%>%
  filter(Soilwater =="optimal")%>%
  summarise(MeanOptimal = mean(Soil_N))'''      Now, I can't use <mutate(MeanOptimal = mean_optimal$MeanOptimal) because of two diversity levels needed. I am not sure how to post code chunks @dharman

Comment: No prob. In a comment, there is no "code chunk", you can wrap an expression in back-ticks `like this` to stress something. Inside a post, use opening and closing 3 back-ticks around your code (and indent the code). I do not have the time right now to update my answer. For a start, create a `MeanOptimal` column based on your diversity levels. Think about the order of your levels (and sequence within the level) , combine this as a vector and inject it. With another `mutate()` call you can then calc the difference (or any other desired output again.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This is how I was able to do it even if it took me around an hour to figure out one simple thing.  ```df%>%  group_by(Soilwater, Replicate)%>%
  mutate(average = Soil_N - mean_optimal$MeanOptimal)%>%
  group_by(Diversity, Replicate)%>%
  filter(Soilwater != "optimal")``` I am sure there are better ways to do this though.

Comment: If you lift your filter variable into the `group_by()`, e.g. `group_by(Diversity, Replicate, Soilwater) %>% summarise( ... operation you need)` then you get all "groups" for the variants of Soilwater. In your case `optimal, 40, 30, ...`. If you want to get "optimal" and "non-optimal", I suggest you create a new column and label your data rows accordingly. Then use this new variable within your `group_by()` and `summarise()` for calculating the summary statistics of the labelled rows.